# Como atualizar uma coluna uma vez por página vizualizada?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, session

Eu estou tentando criar um hit counter, esse código atualiza a minha coluna 1 vez por sessão, mas o que eu quero é que atualize a minha coluna sempre que o usuario vizualizar uma nova página.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['counter'])){    
$_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
$mread = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id = :id");
$mread->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$mread->execute();
};
```

Se eu somente usar a query `UPDATE` ele vai atualizar a minha coluna sempre que eu recarregar a página, e não é isso que eu quero. Eu quero que atualize a minha coluna sempre que o usuario vizualizar uma nova página.

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque em uma variável o nome de cada página, ex:

pagina1.php `$nomePagina="pagina1";`

pagina2.php `$nomePagina="pagina2";`

**código da pagina1.php**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();

    $nomePagina="pagina1";

    if(empty($_SESSION[$nomePagina])){

      ..........
      ..........


      $_SESSION[$nomePagina] = 1;

      //UPDATE

   };
```

Comment: Eu tenho uma duvida, não precisa de um `session_destroy`? Eu não costumo usar o `session_start();` então eu queria saber isso.

Comment: Boa vovô! Eu sempre dou nome também às páginas.

Comment: @Natalie, tem que usar `session_start();`, senão vai incrementar o contador sempre. Quanto ao `session_destroy` não sei direito o que ele faz, vez que testei nesse código do contador e não alterou nada.

Comment: @sam, fala titio, que tal? https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png

Comment: aha... nossa mãe! rs